# gem install mysql problem in rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

Im getting an error with a rails app.

> The bundled mysql.rb driver has been
>   removed from Rails 2.2. Please install
>   the mysql gem and try again: gem
>   install mysql.

And when i try to do gem install mysql it still doesnt work and im getting this error.

> WARNING:  Installing to ~/.gem since
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8 and      /usr/bin
>   aren't both writable. WARNING:  You
>   don't have
>   /Users/bartligthart/.gem/ruby/1.8/bin
>   in your PATH,       gem executables will
>   not run.

I also tried this but it didn't work

> sudo gem install mysql −− −−with−mysql−config≡/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config

what could i do to install mysql?

Comment: What is the error when you run with sudo?

Comment: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lm... yes
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lz... yes
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lsocket... no
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lnsl... no
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no

Comment: checking for main() in -lmygcc... no
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you need to install this first:

```
apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you install the MySQL db server? If so, does this file actually exist?:

```
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config
```

If mysql isn't installed, install that first. Then make sure that the mysql_config script you point to is actually there.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me is adding this to ~/.bash_profile:

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/mysql/lib/
```

After installing the MySQL gem like this (64 bit version on an Intel osx 10.6):

```
export ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" ; sudo gem install --no-rdoc --no-ri mysql -v 2.7 -- --with-mysql-dir=/usr/local --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
sudo gem update --include-dependencies
sudo gem install mysql
sudo apt-get install libsqlite3-dev
sudo gem install sqlite3-ruby
```

Comment: when i did the sude gem install mysql
it gave this error

ERROR:  Error installing mysql:
 ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

Answer (score 0):

This article helped me at the time:
http://craiccomputing.blogspot.com/2008/11/installing-rails-22-on-mac-os-x-mysql.html

Answer (score 0):

To fix that, add "gem: --no-user-install"  in your ~/.gemrc file
[via](http://twitter.com/Caius/status/3709604974)